# Tableview across to another tableview and custom table cell cannot be shown

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

From a tableview to another table view (using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5).

FirstPage.h

```
#import "FavoritesController.h"

#import "Profiles.h"

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FavoritesController * favoriteview = [[FavoritesController alloc] init];
    [favoriteview setTitle:@"Favorites"];

    NSMutableArray * profiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
    profiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

    Profiles * profile = [[Profiles alloc]init];
    profile.profile_name = @"Woot";
    profile.biz_type_desc = @"Woot 1";
    profile.profile_address = @"123, woot";
    profile.profile_email = @"woot@woot.com";
    [profiles addObject:profile];
    profile=[[Profiles alloc]init];
    profile.profile_name = @"Jin-Aurora";
    profile.biz_type_desc = @"Software";
    profile.profile_address = @"682A";
    profile.profile_email = @"jin@jin.biz";
    [profiles addObject:profile];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:favoriteview animated:YES];
    favoriteview.profilelist = profiles; 
}
```

FavoriesController.h

```
@interface FavoritesController : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray * profilelist;

@end
```

FavoriteController.m

```
 #import "FavoritesController.h"
 #import "Profiles.h"
 #import "ProfileCell.h"

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [self.profilelist count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProfileCell";

    ProfileCell *cell = (ProfileCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Profiles * profile = [self.profilelist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.nameLabel.text = profile.profile_name;
    cell.biztypeLabel.text = profile.biz_type_desc;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Storyboard Table View

- [Picture of prototype cell xib with Identity inspector](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/215/screenshot20120208at102k.png/)
- [Picture of prototype cell xib with Attributes inspector](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/197/screenshot20120208at102.png/)

This is the error I got

> 2012-02-08 22:28:37.719 test[4668:f803] Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception **'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here:

```
NSMutableArray * profiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
profiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
```

The first line creates a new mutable array called profiles. The second line creates an autoreleased mutable array with capacity 20 and assigns it to profiles. So you're basically covering up the array you created in the first line. You can either say

```
NSMutableArray *profiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *profiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
```

The reason you're crashing, as mentioned by @wattson12 is that you are dequeueing a cell that hasn't been created. You always want to try and dequeue a cell, but if one doesn't exist, you need to create one. Again, @wattson12 has provided the necessary code for that task.

Comment: Hi jmstone,my code is like this. ProfileCell *cell = (ProfileCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; if (cell == nil) { cell = [[ProfileCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; } but nothing show on table :(

Comment: If you're not getting any cells, set a breakpoint in that method and see if it even gets hit. If not, the usual culprit is that your datasource is saying there aren't any rows in that section (see what the numberOfRowsInSection method returns).

Comment: hi jmstone, it returns me tableViewCellStyleDefault due to i put in initWithStyle, i set cell.textLabel.text = profile.profile_name. it able to show. but i wan to show the custom table cell :( What should i put in InitWithStyle for my custom table view cell?

Comment: When you say custom table cell, are you loading the cell from a nib?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863775/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-within-a-storyboard

Answer (score 2):

your cellForRowAtIndexPath method attempts to dequeue a reusable cell, but doesnt create it if it is not found (which will happen if there are no cells available to reuse)

```
ProfileCell *cell = (ProfileCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell)
    cell = [[[ProfileCell alloc] initWithStyle:style reusueIdentifier:CellIdenfitier] autorelease];
```

Comment: Hi wattson,my code is like this. ProfileCell *cell = (ProfileCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ProfileCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    } but nothing displayed on the table, by the way how you define style?

Comment: that looks ok, check to make sure that method is being called, maybe [self.profileList count] is returning 0. style is defined in the [UITableView](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=uitableview&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2FIOs%2Fdocumentation%2FUIKit%2FReference%2FUITableView_Class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=CJUzT-HfD8HH0QW1-7CyAg&usg=AFQjCNFNYcfigQMvMDGR-pLVt9t5jFVlow) docs

Comment: hi wattson, i put UITableCellStyleDefault, and it shown me default table cell. i missed out something so that custom table cell unable to show. any way can help? :(

Comment: if you are using a custom table view cell and setting up your views in init/layout subviews then it doesnt matter what style you put, just use default. I dont use interface builder so not sure if the way you have set up your cell is right

Comment: i customize my table cell on storyboard, change the identifier to "ProfileCell", create a UITableViewCell named as "ProfileCell" and replace the class of table cell. I dont know where am i miss out. besides this way, how to do it without using interface builder? Please advice :)

Comment: basically you just subclass uitableviewcell like you would any other object, set up views in init, and set their positions in layoutSubviews

Comment: sign, dont know what's wrong with that, i can get the custom cell if i put the tableview at tabBarController. But if i push the TableView from tableview, it show me that : ncyExceTerminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsisteption', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: .going to insane already :(

Answer (score 1):

Notice that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: are different methods.

The following link below may help you.

[Assertion failure in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath)