# Assertion failure in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I was making an rss reader for my school and finished the code. I ran the test and it gave me that error. Here is the code it's referring to:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = 
     [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = 
         [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  
                                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
```

here's the error in the output:

> 2012-10-04 20:13:05.356 Reader[4390:c07] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:4460 2012-10-04
>   20:13:05.357 Reader[4390:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to
>   dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class
>   for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1c90e78 0xb64f35 0xc7d14 0x39ff 0xd0f4b 0xd101f 0xb980b 0xca19b 0x6692d 0x10e26b0
>   0x228dfc0 0x228233c 0x228deaf 0x1058cd 0x4e1a6 0x4ccbf 0x4cbd9 0x4be34
>   0x4bc6e 0x4ca29 0x4f922 0xf9fec 0x46bc4 0x47311 0x2cf3 0x137b7 0x13da7
>   0x14fab 0x26315 0x2724b 0x18cf8 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5
>   0x1c06962 0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x147da 0x1665c 0x2a02 0x2935)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

and here's the code it shows in the error screen:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assertion Failure in UITableViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798444/assertion-failure-in-uitableviewcontroller)

Answer (score 489, accepted):

You're using the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method.  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) for that method says this:

> **Important:** You must register a class or nib file using the `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method before calling this method.

You didn't register a nib or a class for the reuse identifier `"Cell"`.

Looking at your code, you seem to expect the dequeue method to return `nil` if it doesn't have a cell to give you.  You need to use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` for that behavior:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Notice that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` are different methods. See doc for [the former](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:) and [the latter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:).

If you want to understand why you'd want to ever use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, [check out this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25826383/77567).

Comment: OMG.  Why does Xcode's default template for a UITableViewController automatically give you dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:?  So unhelpful.

Comment: The `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer:forIndexPath:` (introduced in iOS6) is a nice improvement, since you don't need to check if the cell is nil. (So `UITableViewController` works similar to `UICollectionView`) But yeah, annoying that this change isn't comment in the template and that the assertion/crash message isn't more helpful.

Comment: At the very least you'd think that it would default to UITableViewCell instead of imploding.  Baka.

Comment: The last line of this answer is golden: I've been bitten more than once by using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` when I should've been using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: This answer is perfect. I have a question: I have a tableViewController as my initial view controller. At didSelectRow... I'm pushing another tableViewController onto the navigation stack. How come I only have to register a cell for the second tableViewController, not the initial?

Comment: To take the pain out our dequeuing cells, use Reusable https://github.com/AliSoftware/Reusable, its soooo good

Answer (score 139):

I think this error is about registering your nib or class for the identifier.

So that you may keep what you are doing in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath function and just add code below into your viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

It's worked for me. Hope it may help.

Comment: One small gotcha with this - make sure that reuse identifier matches what you have set up in your Storyboard settings for the cell in question.

Comment: Just to add to this on a slightly different use case, I was reselecting a row in the Master view of my SplitViewController. This reselect row logic was in the `viewDidLoad` and moving this logic to `viewDidAppear` fixed it.

Comment: It could not enter in cell==nil , So my tableview cell always nil.

Comment: swift 3.0: 
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier:"Cell");

Answer (score 70):

Although this question is fairly old, there is another possibility:
If you are using Storyboards, you simply have to set the CellIdentifier in the Storyboard.

So if your CellIdentifier is "Cell", just set the "Identifier" property:
[image]

**Make sure to clean your build after doing so. XCode sometimes has some issues with Storyboard updates**

Comment: you are awesome, cleaning does a lot !! :D

Comment: Note - if you use an identifier other than "Cell" you'll also need to change your cellForRowAtIndexPath method to use this identifer in the following line: static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";

Comment: One important addition to this: The table view must have its "Content" attribute set to "Dynamic Prototypes", NOT "Static Cells"

Comment: This answer needs to come higher. Very helpful

Comment: Cleaning build was essential after updating the `Identifier` property. Thanks!

Comment: Well done! 'Product>Clean' did it for me after setting this value.

Answer (score 60):

i had the same problem replacing with

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
```

solved

Comment: tip: if you use a **-(id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:**, dont need verify if cell is nil. (IOS6>)

Comment: just saved me a headache. =)

Answer (score 28):

The problem is most likely because you config custom `UITableViewCell` in storyboard but you do not use storyboard to instantiate your `UITableViewController` which uses this `UITableViewCell`. For example, in MainStoryboard, you have a `UITableViewController` subclass called `MyTableViewController` and have a custom dynamic `UITableViewCell` called `MyTableViewCell` with identifier id "MyCell".

If you create your custom `UITableViewController` like this:

```
 MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
```

It will not automatically register your custom tableviewcell for you. You have to manually register it.

But if you use storyboard to instantiate `MyTableViewController`, like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewController"];
```

Nice thing happens! `UITableViewController` will automatically register your custom tableview cell that you define in storyboard for you.

In your delegate method "cellForRowAtIndexPath", you can create you table view cell like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

//Configure your cell here ...

return cell;
}
```

dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will automatically create new cell for you if there is not reusable cell available in the recycling queue.

Then you are done!

Comment: The tip that using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to init my viewController saved my day!

Comment: saved my day: prototype cells were in the neighbouring VC with a table

Comment: This is the reasonable cause in my case.

Answer (score 20):

I'll just add that *Xcode 4.5* includes the new `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`
in its default template code - a potential gotcha for developers expecting the older `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method.

Comment: Stung me!  Now I'll know better. ;)

Answer (score 19):

### Swift 2.0 solution:

You need to go into your Attribute Inspector and add a name for your cells Identifier:

[image]

Then you need to make your identifier match with your dequeue like this:

```
let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ButtonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ButtonCell
```

**Alternatively**

If you're working with a nib you may need to register your class in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {       

    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SwitchCell")

    // included for context            
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SwitchCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! SwitchCell

    //... continue    
}
```

[Apples's UITableView Class Reference says:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)

> Prior to dequeueing any cells, call this method or the
>   registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: method to tell the table view how
>   to create new cells. If a cell of the specified type is not currently
>   in a reuse queue, the table view uses the provided information to
>   create a new cell object automatically.
>
> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse
>   identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces
>   the old entry. You may specify nil for cellClass if you want to
>   unregister the class from the specified reuse identifier.

Here's the code from Apples Swift 2.0 framework:

```
// Beginning in iOS 6, clients can register a nib or class for each cell.
// If all reuse identifiers are registered, use the newer -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: to guarantee that a cell instance is returned.
// Instances returned from the new dequeue method will also be properly sized when they are returned.

@available(iOS 5.0, *)
func registerNib(nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)

@available(iOS 6.0, *)
func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

Comment: I don't understand where `SwitchCell.self` is coming from?

Comment: @GertCuykens SwitchCell is my custom UITableViewCell

Comment: I'm away from my Mac right now, but I can definitely update it when I get home.

Comment: Replacing it with `UITableViewCell.self` seem to work for me. Maybe add a note in the answer

Comment: @GertCuykens thanks for pointing that out, I've changed SwitchCell.self for UITableViewCell.self

Answer (score 18):

In your storyboard you should set the 'Identifier' of your prototype cell to be the same as your CellReuseIdentifier "Cell". Then you won't get that message or need to call that registerClass: function.

Comment: Gotcha! Where is the '100 upvotes'-button. This is the real solution.

Comment: You would think that adding a new tableView into a storyboard will provide a default identifier - 'Cell' for you. It's so easily overlooked especially if you are using the so called 'free code' in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath!

Answer (score 3):

If you are going with **Custom Static Cells** just comment this method:

```
//- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"notificationCell";
//    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
//    return cell;
//}
```

and give the cells an identifier at **"Attributes Inspector"** in storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

I give you the answer in both Objective C and Swift.Before that I want to say

> If we use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`,we must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method as 
>   [Apple Documnetation Says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:)

So we add `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`

> Once we registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead.

in viewDidLoad method we should register the cell

**Objective C**

**OPTION 1:**

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

**OPTION 2:**

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

in above code `nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell"` give your nib name instead of my nib name CustomCell

**SWIFT**

**OPTION 1:**

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

**OPTION 2:**

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NameInput", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

in above code `nibName:"NameInput"` give your nib name

Answer (score 3):

Working with Swift 3.0:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.myList.register(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = myList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours last night working out why my programmatically generated table crashed on [myTable setDataSource:self]; It was OK commenting out and popping up an empty table, but crashed every time I tried to reach the datasource;

I had the delegation set up in the h file: @interface myViewController : UIViewController

I had the data source code in my implementation and still BOOM!, crash every time! THANK YOU to "xxd" (nr 9): adding that line of code solved it for me!  In fact I am launching a table from a IBAction button, so here is my full code:

```
    - (IBAction)tapButton:(id)sender {

    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;

    //Add the table
    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)         style:UITableViewStylePlain];

   // NEXT THE LINE THAT SAVED MY SANITY Without it the program built OK, but crashed when      tapping the button!

    [table registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    table.delegate=self;
    [table setDataSource:self];
    [popoverView addSubview:table];
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
    CGSizeMake(200, 300);

    //create a popover controller
    popoverController3 = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                          initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    CGRect popRect = CGRectMake(self.tapButton.frame.origin.x,
                                self.tapButton.frame.origin.y,
                                self.tapButton.frame.size.width,
                                self.tapButton.frame.size.height);


    [popoverController3 presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];



   }


   #Table view data source in same m file

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
    NSLog(@"Sections in table");
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
  {
    NSLog(@"Rows in table");

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return myArray.count;
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *myValue;

    //This is just some test array I created:
    myValue=[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text=myValue;
    UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 12.0 ];
    cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;

    return cell;
   }
```

By the way: the button must be linked up with as an IBAction and as a IBOutlet if you want to anchor the popover to it.

UIPopoverController *popoverController3 is declared in the H file directly after @interface between {}

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I got this same error when I forgot to set the cell identifier in the storyboard.  If this is your issue then in the storyboard click the table view cell and set the cell identifier in the attributes editor.  Make sure the cell identifier you set here is the same as

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YourCellIdenifier";
```

Answer (score 2):

I setup everything correctly in the Storyboard and did a clean build but kept getting the error " *must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard*"

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Corrected the error but i'm still at a loss. I'm not using a 'custom cell', just a view with a tableview embeded. I have declared the viewcontroller as delegate and datasource and made sure the cell identifier matches in file. whats going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, was having the same error and for me it worked like this:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:CELL_NIB_HERE bundle: nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER_HERE];
```

Maybe it will be usefull for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem stupid to some people but it got me. I was getting this error and the problem for me was that I was trying to use static cells but then dynamically add more stuff. If you are calling this method your cells need to be dynamic prototypes. Select the cell in storyboard and under the Attributes inspector, the very first thing says 'Content' and you should select dynamic prototypes not static.

Answer (score 1):

Just a supplement of the answers:
There may be a time you set all things right, but you may accidentally add some other UIs in you `.xib`, like a `UIButton`:[image]
Just delete the extra UI, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the CellIdentifier == identifier of the cell in a storyboard, both names are same. Hope this works for u

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the crash happened when I called`deselectRowAtIndexPath:`

The line was `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

Changing it to `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` **FIXED MY PROBLEM!**

Hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 0):

In Swift this problem can be solved by adding the following code in your

> viewDidLoad

method.

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForKeyedArchiver(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "your_reuse_identifier")
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to be aware that when using `interface builder` and creating a `Xib` (nib) containing **one** cell that there is also a `placeholder` created that points to the class that will be used. Meaning, when you place two `UITableViewCell` in one Xib file you possibly run into the exact same trouble causing an `*** Assertion failure ...`. The placeholder mechanism doesn't work adn will be confused then. Instead placing different placeholders in one Xib read on..

The most easy solution (even if that seems a bit to simple) is to place **one Cell** at a time **in one Xib**. IB will create a placeholder for you and all works as expected then. But this then leads directly to one extra line of code, because then you need to load the correct nib/xib asking for the reuseIdentified Cell where it resides in.
So the following example code focuses the use of multiple Cell Indentifiers in one tableview where an Assertion Failure is very common.

```
// possibly above class implementation
static NSString *firstCellIdentifier = @"firstCellIdentifier";
static NSString *secondCellIdentifier = @"secondCellIdentifier";

// possibly in -(instancetype)init 
UINib *firstNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"FirstCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:firstNib forCellReuseIdentifier:firstCellIdentifier];
UINib *secondNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SecondCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:secondNib forCellReuseIdentifier:secondCellIdentifier];
```

Another trouble with the use of two CellIdentifier's in one UITableView is that row height and/or section height have to be taken care of. Two cells can have different heights of course.

When registering classes for *reuse* the code should look different.

The "simple solution" looks also much different when your cells reside inside a Storyboard instead of Xib's. Watch out for the placeholders.

Keep also in mind that interface builder files have version wise variations and need to be set to a version that your targeted OS version supports. Even if you may be lucky that the particular feature you placed in your Xib is not changed since the last IB version and does not throw errors yet. So a Xib made with IB set to be compatible to `iOS 13+` but used in a target that is compiled on an earlier version `iOS 12.4` will cause also trouble and can end up with Assertion failure.

Answer (score -1):

Ran into this error bc cell re-use identifier was wrong-- a rookie mistake but it happens:
1.  Makes SURE cell re-use idenifier has no misspellings or missing letters.
2.  Along same line, don't forget capitalization counts.
3.  Zeroes are not "O"s (Ohs)