# Cell identifier not found when the UITableVC is contained in another VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a table view with some custom cells, but I have a problem. Everything is setup correctly and when I use this UITableVC as the initial VC it all works. But when I try to add it as a child VC to another VC, I get this error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:4460
2013-02-05 18:37:25.704 SalesBot[16284:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Statement Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I'm not changing anything else, I'm just moving the arrow in the storyboard to another VC to make it initial.

Here is how I'm adding the UITableVC subclass as a child to another VC:

```
self.statementTableViewController = [[SBStatementTableViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:self.statementTableViewController.view];
[self.statementTableViewController.view setFrame:self.contentFrame];
```

And here is how I dequeue a cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Statement Cell";
    SBStatementCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

*I understand the above code is iOS6 only, I will worry about iOS 5 later :)*

I'm guessing that the cell identifiers are somehow not "global" and the tableVC can't see them when it's a child to another VC?

Please help and let me know if you need to see some more code!

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize the cell? It should look something like UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview deque...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have yet to follow up with your code, I'm willing to bet this is your issue.

**Taken from:** [Assertion failure in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath)

You're using the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: method. The documentation for that method says this:

```
Important: You must register a class or nib file using the 
registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:
method before calling this method.
```

You didn't register a nib or a class for the reuse identifier "Cell".

Looking at your code, you seem to expect the dequeue method to return nil if it doesn't have a cell to give you. You need to use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: for that behavior:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Notice that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: are different methods.

Comment: I have noticed that, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: is iOS 6+ only. I will try to make the suggested changes and see what happens. In the meantime, why am I not getting this error when the table VC is not a child of another VC? (when it's the initial VC)

Comment: @NikolayDyankov I admittedly have no idea why it would work as the parent viewcontroller.

Comment: That was the essence of my question :)

Comment: I added registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: and it doesn't crash anymore, BUT - when the tableVC is a child I can't set any values for the labels in the cells. Works fine when the table VC is the initial VC.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov Strange. I wonder if there's something else going on in the code that's causing that? Either way, I think your safest bet is to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: and check for the null cell. That way its supported in iOS 6 and below.

Comment: I ended up slapping a UITableView instead of a child UITableVC and just implemented the protocols. Working so far... (fingers crossed)