# Accessory arrow in table not showed in master detail project with search bar

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Using XCode 4.5.2 I have created a Master/Detail iOS 6.0 project from template. The generated project already contains disclosure indicator ">" in table cell and detail view opens when table row is tapped. Then:

1. I added the Search Bar and Search Display Controller above the master table
2. According to the [following problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath) I added UITableViewCell class registration in MasterViewController's method 
   `- (void)viewDidLoad`

`[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];`

After this registerClass line is added I run the program in simulator. The disclosure indicator is not shown in table cells and the detail view does not open when the table row is tapped.

I followed the advice [here](http://code.thewebanalyzers.com/2011/11/how-to-add-arrow-disclosure-indicator-button-checkmark-in-table-view/) that adds disclosure indicator back but the detail view still does not open when table row is tapped.

What else is needed?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.
Also, check if `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which enables to even get rid of:

```
     [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

Solution is:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

in method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

diff is: **self.** which need to be added to Xcode generated template (for Master/Detail).