# Why am I getting an error about being unable to dequeue when my UITableView tries to load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I get the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier FontCell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I set the cell identifier (programmatically, as it's not created through Interface Builder) and do everything I thought I was supposed to do in the delegate methods, but I'm still getting that error when I try to get the UITableView to load.

Here's the relevant code (it's worth noting I've subclassed UITableViewCell for customization options):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.fonts.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FontCell";

    FontCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[FontCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"FontCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    int row = indexPath.row;

    cell.fontFamilyLabel.text = self.fonts[row];

    return cell;
}
```

And here's the only method I changed in my subclassed UITableViewCell (FontCell):

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.fontFamilyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 20)];
        self.fontFamilyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.fontFamilyLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found this thread it has a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Easiest fix is to just change it to `FontCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];`  As with your current code, you'll have to check to be sure `cell` is not `nil` if you do this method.

---

Alternately, you can register a `UINib` or `Class` at the table level that is tied to `@"FontCell"`

For example (up in `viewDidLoad`):

```
[self.tableView registerClass: [FontCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FontCell"];
```

Then you can do

```
FontCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FontCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The nice thing with this method is that you know that your cell will never be `nil`, so you can just immediately begin modifying it.

Comment: What if I change the identifier for each cell. I don't think it will work is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

You're using the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method. The documentation for that method says this:

```
You must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.
```

So here

```
[self.tableView registerClass: [FontCell class] forReuseIdentifier: @"FontCell"];
```

Comment: Probably should register his `FontCell` class, which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @Brian Yeah when using custom cell register that cell

Comment: it should be     [self.tableView registerClass:[FontCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FontCell"];

Answer (score 2):

I also had such a problem, and the solution I found is:

Go to the Project Navigator and select “ViewController.h”. Append

```
 <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

after “UIViewController”.

Comment: What is this? What that do?

Answer (score 1):

If using a tableview (not a table view controller) as I was, there are not cells that appear by default.

In the storyboard select the tableview
Open the Attributes inspector
Change prototype cells from 0 to 1
Select the newly displayed table cell
In the Attributes inspector set the Identitifier to "FontCell"