# Login screen before masterview/navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm still new to objective -c. I have everything else working but I just can't wrap my head around this login screen atm.

I can log in but after that, my app crashes and I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

But without the login screen, it works fine. My storyboard looks like this:

[image]

Could someone lend a hand?

Comment: Do you have a prototype cell for the tableView?

Comment: @CaptJak Yes. Everything was working fine before I added the login screen to my storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not really inside your login screen, but in the `MasterViewController`. With some breakpoints, you should see that your present controller is allocated, it's `viewDidLoad` is probably called.

But inside some method of the tableView's delegate implementation (probably `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) your code crashes. Make sure to have a correct implementation of the tableView's methods, using a identifier for cell in your XIB/Storyboard (or registering with `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method ,etc.

This link should help you with the problem: [Why am I getting an error about being unable to dequeue when my UITableView tries to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773275/why-am-i-getting-an-error-about-being-unable-to-dequeue-when-my-uitableview-trie)