# how to add a UItableview without storyboard? (UITableView error )

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use swift add an UITableview (without storyboard), but an error happened , I don't why

The error is

> 2015-06-26 11:08:14.149 test[62289:4994907] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:6245
>
> 2015-06-26 11:08:14.152 test[62289:4994907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TextCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I don't know how to figure it out

The source is :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    let swiftBlogs = ["a","b","c","d"]

    let textCellIndetifier = "TextCell"

    var t = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
        t.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(t)
    
        t.delegate = self
        t.dataSource = self
    
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return swiftBlogs.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = t.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIndetifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = swiftBlogs[row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        t.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    
        let row = indexPath.row
        println(swiftBlogs[row])
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an error about being unable to dequeue when my UITableView tries to load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773275/why-am-i-getting-an-error-about-being-unable-to-dequeue-when-my-uitableview-trie)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to register the cell you're using, since you don't have a storyboard, you need to make a UITableViewCell element in a XIB file.

```
override func ViewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextCell")
}
```