# Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Can anybody tell me why am I getting this error?

Here's my .m file:

```
#import "ListaParticipantesViewController.h"
#import "Participantes.h"
#import "ModParticipantesViewController.h"

@implementation ListaParticipantesViewController

@synthesize dao;
@synthesize participantes;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    dao = [[ParticipantesDAO alloc] init];
    participantes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    participantes = [dao getDatos];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [participantes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"celda";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[participantes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"nombre"];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ModParticipantesViewController *destino = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"visualizacion"];
    Participantes *tmp = [participantes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    destino.participante = tmp;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destino animated:YES];
}

@end
```

and the error displayed is:

```
2013-04-13 17:40:20.235 Registro[5314:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:5471
2013-04-13 17:40:20.237 Registro[5314:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x209d012 0x11aae7e 0x209ce78 0xc40665 0x1a4c1b 0x13940c 0x1a4a7b 0x1a9919 0x1a99cf 0x1921bb 0x1a2b4b 0x13f2dd 0x11be6b0 0x2699fc0 0x268e33c 0x2699eaf 0x1de2bd 0x126b56 0x12566f 0x125589 0x1247e4 0x12461e 0x1253d9 0x1282d2 0x1d299c 0x11f574 0x11f76f 0x11f905 0x128917 0xec96c 0xed94b 0xfecb5 0xffbeb 0xf1698 0x1ff8df9 0x1ff8ad0 0x2012bf5 0x2012962 0x2043bb6 0x2042f44 0x2042e1b 0xed17a 0xeeffc 0x306d 0x1ef5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assertion failure in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath)

Comment: You get this assertion when you return **nil** to `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 14):

The storyboard or XIB does not have a cell defined with the cell identifier you specified.

Comment: Wow thanks! so the first error is gone... i just keep getting 2013-04-13 19:35:07.303 Registro[6194:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Participantes 0x8054f40> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nombreParticipante.'

Answer (score 5):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  return cell; // at the end of your method 
}
```

Comment: Weirdly, i'm back to this page months later to comment instead of answer, but your answer helped me out this time! My cell was NULL when logged so i checked my initialisation and i was using [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER"] , which should have been obvious as i was moving my code away from my storyboard! Thanks anyway. "Check your cell initialisation, kids"

Answer (score 4):

You need to set delegate and datasource of tableview in header.

Objecitve c

```
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Swift

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Have you subclassed your ListaParticipantesViewController with the classes UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource? They are needed to be able to use delegate and data source methods.

In Swift:

```
class ListaParticipantesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the very same error. It turns out it was the same problem, that it couldn't find my cell identifier, but for a different reason - I was subclassing UITableViewCell, but hadn't registered my .XIB file with my UITableView for a reuseIdentifier.

I solved it by resgitering in the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //LOAD XIB
  UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NAME_OF_NIB_FILE"
                              bundle:nil];

  //REGISTER XIB, CONTAINING THE CELL (IDENTIFIER NAME USUALLY SAME AS NIB NAME)
  [[self tableView] registerNib:nib
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_NAME"]; 
}
```

And then creating the cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  //GET THE RECYCLED CELL
  TableCellSubclass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_NAME"];

  //CONFIGURE THE CELL

  return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a simple mistake..

My number of rows was defined by array.count.

When I refreshed this array I was removing all the objects, initiating the connection, adding the objects to the array and then reloading the tableview.

I put the objects removal once the connection was completed and it solved my issue.