# xcode tableview error pointing on main file

Tags: uitableview, tableview

i am trying to display record from mysql database by connecting and fatching data through PHP

the error is pointing in following line

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
     @autoreleasepool {
      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

   }
   }
```

error output

```
  2013-07-17 20:42:51.148 plan[738:11303] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView     
  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-
  2380.17/UITableView.m:4460

  2013-07-17 20:42:51.158 plan[738:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     
  exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with 
  identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a  
  prototype cell in a storyboard'

  *** First throw call stack:
  (0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1c90e78 0xb64665 0xc46c4 0x2c78 0xcd8fb 0xcd9cf 0xb61bb 0xc6b4b   
  0x632dd 0x10e26b0 0x228dfc0 0x228233c 0x228deaf 0x1022bd 0x4ab56 0x4966f 0x49589  
  0x487e4 0x4861e 0x493d9 0x4c2d2 0xf699c 0x43574 0x4376f 0x43905 0x4c917 0x1096c 
  0x1194b 0x22cb5 0x23beb 0x15698 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 0x1c37bb6 
  0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1117a 0x12ffc 0x242d 0x2355)
  libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
  (lldb)
```

please help me in this regard.

Comment: It's not `main()`, it's just the debugger being dumb. Symbolicate.

Comment: how i can solve the error....

Comment: the error output looks like it gives you a reason for the crash. I would start there

Comment: @LisaPink That's what I'm trying to figure out... But since I'm not an agent from the Matrix, I can't mind-read raw hex addresses. **Symbolicate.**

Comment: symbolication is totally uneccessary. **'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with 
  identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a  
  prototype cell in a storyboard'**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assertion failure in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath)

Answer (score 0):

possible reason is you dont have tableview and cell in nib file or connection is missing..Do connect the table from nib and code