# Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

For some reason my app is failing when trying to load up the cells into the tableview.  All of my tableviews throughout the app are exactly the same and i have no issues with them.  Could it possible have to do with initializing the Controller from another viewController?  I wouldn't think so.   My cell in the storyboard has been given the identifier.  Here is a link to a screen shot.

[image]

So i have tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath) and nothing has worked.

Here is the output using the [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath] method:

```
2013-11-14 15:36:33.419 ComplyOS[43683:70b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:5261
2013-11-14 15:36:33.424 ComplyOS[43683:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception    'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ProcedureCell - must register a    nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fa9795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101d0c991 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101fa961a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x00000001018a99e9 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
4   UIKit                               0x00000001008f9879 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 150
5   ComplyOS                            0x00000001000099b4 -[EndoPxTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 116
6   UIKit                               0x0000000100902b8a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 348
7   UIKit                               0x00000001008ea836 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2297
8   UIKit                               0x00000001008fb381 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207
9   UIKit                               0x0000000100892b27 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
10  QuartzCore                          0x00000001005afa22 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
11  QuartzCore                          0x00000001005a4589 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
12  QuartzCore                          0x00000001005a440a _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100519694 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010051a70c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010051ad79 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f74ff7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f74f67 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f546d2 __CFRunLoopRun + 946
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f53f33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103c2b3a0 GSEventRunModal + 161
21  UIKit                               0x0000000100837043 UIApplicationMain + 1010
22  Comply                              0x0000000100002703 main + 115
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001029ed5fd start + 1
24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

And here is my code for the UITableView Controller:

```
#import "EndoPxTableViewController.h"
#import <AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h>
#import "ProcedureTableViewCell.h"

@interface EndoPxTableViewController (){}

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *procedures;
@end

@implementation EndoPxTableViewController


- (void)setVisitItem:(Patient_VisitsModel *)visitItem{
if(_visitItem !=visitItem){
    _visitItem = visitItem;
     }
}

 -(void)setUserId:(NSString *)userId{
     if(_userId !=userId){
         _userId = userId;
    }
[self fetchProceduresData];
}


- (void) fetchProceduresData{
NSString *procedureURLString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://XXXX";


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:procedureURLString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id json) {


    _procedures = json;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error occured in getSessionID method");
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
 }

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
}
return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"Endoscopy Report";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"Procedures:%@", [_procedures valueForKey:@"description"]);
return _procedures.count;
 }

 - (ProcedureTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProcedureCell";
ProcedureTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *procedureDescription = [_procedures[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"description"];
NSLog(@"Procedure Description:%@", procedureDescription);


cell.procedureLabel.text = procedureDescription;
cell.questionImage.image = nil;

return cell;
 }

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
}

@end
```

Thanks for everyones help.  I am getting a little desperate.

Comment: It seems that you are using a custom class `ProcedureTableViewCell` for your custom cell. Please make sure that you are not replacing the cell identifier somehow inside it

Comment: All i did in that class was assign the IBOutlets for label and UIImage.

Comment: Did you set the `Class` of your Prototype Cell to be `ProcedureTableViewCell`. Is `ProcedureTableViewCell` a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Prototype does have the class of ProcedureTableViewCell, it is a subclass if UITableViewCell.

Comment: The class for the prototype cell should have been set to `ProcedureTableViewCell` from identity inspector, as it seems like from your design

Comment: The class from the identity inspector is set to ProcedureTableViewCell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assertion failure in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath)

Comment: @AyanSengupta what does it mean that ' make sure that you are not replacing the cell identifier somehow inside it' ? identifier is defined at storyboard and I know that there is no code modifying the identifier

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My bad! It seems to be you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method for dequeueing cell. Please try `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` instead and it should work.

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` expects a nib file or a registered class for dequeueing cells but you are using storyboard prototype cell. And `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is guaranteed to return a cell from storyboard if you use correct identifier.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tada....I had tried that before and it did not work.  I dont know what i did differently but it loaded up the view with the correct number of cells.  Now I have to figure out why it is not loading the "procedureDescription" into each of the cells.  The NSLog is logging out just fine...

Comment: @LKM I am not sure what didn't work out for you and not sure about your issue as well. I think this answer is not meant for your issue. Thanks.

Comment: nil return on cell

Comment: @gowtham if you are using a storyboard and prototype cell it is bound to return a cell unless 1. the cell identifier is not specified in storyboard 2. The cell identifier is specified in the storyboard but in some separate VC and 3. the same cell identifier is not used in the code (typo!)

Comment: Thanks my problem is solve reason is "I didn't mention correct tableView"

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem like yours.
I've found what was problem.

In your code,

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProcedureCell";
ProcedureTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

you should use 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:indexPath' method when you use **segue** between view controllers in storyboard(I said 'connecting controllers' in storyboard).

If you just draw your custom cell by using Interface builder, you have to use method like below

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProcedureCell";
    ProcedureTableViewCell *cell = (ProcedureTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ProcedureTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code for configuring your custom cell.

```
 //configure cell
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ProcedureCell";

ProcedureTableViewCell *cell = (ProcedureTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

// If there is no cell to reuse, create a new one
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ProcedureTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}
return cell;
}
```