# UITableView - "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash

Where is the problem?
I want to make a Table View and if u click on the cell it pops up another Table View
What i must to do to fix that?

```
    - (UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"TableViewCell_2"; 
    TableViewController_2 *cell2 = (TableViewController_2)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    // Configure the cell... 
    int row = [indexPath row]; cell2.Spoj = _Spoj[row]; 
    return cell2; 
}
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't set the identifier for your cell (or you're not using the same one in your code and in IB).

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"TableViewCell_2";
    TableViewController_2 *cell2 = (TableViewController_2*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // Configure the cell...
    
    int row = [indexPath row];
    
    cell2.Spoj = _Spoj[row];
    

    
    return cell2;
}

Comment: Where did you make the cell? In IB (xib or storyboard)?

Comment: please, edit your post instead of write the comment. it's difficult to understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/19989266/3476191](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19989266/3476191)

Comment: Your screen shot shows that you didn't give the cell an identifier in IB.

Comment: Set the identifier for your prototype cell in the storyboard, and that will fix your problem at least the one problem that causes the error you posted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` instead of  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Comment: This is wrong. Either method should work if the OP has the correct identifier.

Comment: The documentation is incomplete, and partially wrong. If you make the cell in the storyboard, you can use either method without registering anything. I've done it many times.

Comment: i need to know how to fix this warning:(

Comment: Change `TableViewController_2 *cell2 = (TableViewController_2 *)[…` to `TableViewCell_2 *cell2 = (TableViewCell_2 *)[…`.

Comment: http://screenshot.cz/ZPWUN/Snimka-obrazovky-2014-04-12-o1.47.41.png even worse :D

Comment: At the top of your file, `#import "TableViewCell_2.h"`

Comment: Sorry, I always forget about the case where you don't have a prototype cell (since I never do it that way) -- so you're right that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: will work while the longer method doesn't in that situation unless you do the registration.

Comment: Yeah, I always forget about when you do because I am slow to upgrade to newer technologies.

Answer (score 0):

For correct dequeueing there are these steps:

- On the attributes inspector for the xib file, add the identifier. (not in the restorationID field)
- In your viewDidLoad of the ViewController owning the tableview, register the nib

  [[self.tableview registerNib:[UINib nibWithName@"TheNibName" bundle:nil] withIdentifier:@"theSameIdentierInXib"];
- call dequeue... in cellForRow (no need to cast cell type or check for nil from iOS 5+)

*note, registerClass can cause an assertion failure if used for cell xib.