# Table View Cell and initial cell availability for dequeue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My doubt is about "Prototype Cells" and the method "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" below:

```
func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> AnyObject
```

Let's say that I create a View Cotroller in StoryBoard and attach a Table View to it. In this first scenario I won't attach a Table View Cell to the Table View. Then I create the following class to control my View Controller:

```
import UIKit



class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var myArray: String = [String]["One", "Two", "Three"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testCell") as UITableViewCell!

    // I NEED THIS HERE
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = UITableViewCell()
    }

    cell.textLabel!.text = "Test"

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.myArray.count
}
}
```

Sorry for bad indentation.

In this situation I need the `if statement` in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, to check if the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returned `nil`. If in the StoryBoard I attach a Table View Cell, which will create Protype Cells, to the Table View previously attached and set its identifier to "testCell", do I still need the `if statement` above? I guess not because I will always have cells to be dequeued, but am I right? I am not considering here the situation where I have created the maximum amount of cells allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989266/assertion-failure-in-uitableview-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpat

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: is guaranteed to return a cell from storyboard if you use correct identifier.

Answer (score 0):

dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: is guaranteed to return a cell from storyboard if you use correct identifier so you do not need to test if cell == nil