# UITableView implementation crashes the application but doesn't show an error in the code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I need help understanding why my console returns the error:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <--APP_LOCATION--> (loaded)' with name 'MyListingsTableViewCell''
>   ** First throw call stack: ...

I'm new to using these prototype cells and tables, I will attach the code below. I appreciate any support that you can offer.

Code for the view controller where the prototype cell is implemented as follow:

```
#import "MyListings.h"

@interface MyListings ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *createListingButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation MyListings

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyListingsTableViewCell"];

    UINib *nib1 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyListingsTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib1 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyListingsTableViewCell"];

    titles = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
    currentBids = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"3",@"4", nil];
    stillAvailables = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"5",@"6", nil];

    _createListingButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    _createListingButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
    _createListingButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [_createListingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createListingButtonHighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [_createListingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createListingButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_createListingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createListingButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)createListingButtonHighlightBorder
{
    _createListingButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.61 green:0.00 blue:0.02 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
}

- (void)createListingButtonUnhighlightBorder
{
    _createListingButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [titles count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyListingsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyListingsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell updateCellWithTitle:[titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] currentBid:[currentBids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stillAvailable:[stillAvailables objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Prototype Cell class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)updateCellWithTitle:(NSString *)title currentBid:(NSString *)bid stillAvailable:(NSString *)available
{
    self.titleLabel.text = title;
    self.currentBidLabel.text = bid;
    self.stillAvailableLabel.text = available;
    self.editLabel.text = @"Press to edit";
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526756/unable-to-dequeue-a-cell-with-identifier-cell-must-register-a-nib-or-a-class-f)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that post, we're trying to find the solution to two different failures, which are both associated with prototype cells. Therefore, to summarize, our issues are different, therefore our solutions, in theory, should also be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have created a xib for table view cell then  you need to register like this..

```
UINib *nib1 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyListingsTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib1 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyListingsTableViewCell"];
```

If you have desired you cell in storyboard then you need to specify its custom class and cell reuse identifier...

[image]

[image]

When every you are working with custom cells then you need to one of the following....

- Create a xib and register nib to tableview

or

- Design cell in story board, set custom class and reuse cell identifier.

You did both the things...thats why it was crashing bcoz you are registering "MyListingsTableViewCell" nib to tableview that does not exits.

Connect all IBOutlest like this...

[image]

Set tableview delegate and datasource...

[image]

Or from code also you can set this like below in your MyListings class...

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

Final output...its working fine from your code...

[image]

Comment: then use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"your cell identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];` to reuse cell.

Comment: Have I not already got this in my code? it reads "MyListingsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyListingsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];"

Comment: Then what is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:"

Comment: have you created a xib for cell or designed your cell in storyboard ?

Comment: I designed the cell in my storyboard, then made a class for a UITableViewCell that defines all the properties of this prototype cell I made.

Comment: Ok fine...now check have you set cell's custom class?

Comment: Yes, the class has been set to "MyListingsTableViewCell"

Comment: thats correct, so now check your Cell Reuse Identifier in story board...what you have written there?

Comment: ah, haha. It's had a lower case m this whole time... thanks for assisting me there.

Comment: The application still crashes with the error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: "

Comment: Cell reuse identifier in storyboard and in `cellForRow` is same ? just copy paste it, if not...

Comment: Yes, it's the same, this time. I capitalised the reuse identifier, instead. As every time I call it, it's name is the same, apart from a capital "M" for my

Comment: Can you attach the screen shot of your custom class and cell reuse identifier from story board....as I have attached...see my answer...

Comment: Ok, it's my first time uploading a screenshot here... I HAVE to do it in my initial post, correct?

Comment: Ah, it says I need at least 10 reputation to post images here. Instead, here are the links: https://imgur.com/a/PXgTd and https://imgur.com/2PuUNUk

Comment: Your reuse identifier is correctly set (make sure there is no trailing space)....post image where you have specified custom class in storyboard (i.e. Identity inspector).....not the screen shot of code...

Comment: Ok, I've made sure there's no space.

Comment: Add screen shot where you have specified custom class in storyboard (i.e. Identity inspector)

Comment: Just do one thing....send me code on my email mahendrapatelg.it@gmail.com and Let me check the issue...if possible...

Comment: I've sent you an email with the relevant files attached.

Comment: Not to rush you, but I need a solution for this urgently. If it's not too much to ask for, can you get back to me ASAP, if you're aware of what I'm doing wrong or would prefer to show me an alternative method to achieve the same, desired, outcome?

Comment: I've checked your code....in MyListing.m file you have registered nib, just comment that line.....

Comment: Right on time, I've commented the line and changed "[self.tableView registerClass:[MyListingsTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyListingsTableViewCell"];" this part of the code, too. The change I made was changing "UITableViewCell" to "MyListingsTableViewCell"

Comment: Okay, now, it no longer crashes, however it has a white background (which I can fix), doesn't match the dimensions of the prototype cell, at all, and doesn't have any text or anything inside it...

Comment: Do you know what was the actual problem...?

Comment: From what I now understand, the actual problem was that the code had no idea what "prototype" I was talking about, for the prototype cell(s) that I was trying to instantiate.

Comment: But yeah, the application is no longer crashing, it's just the table view cell isn't populated at all, by anything.

Comment: Ok, I understand this. Do you know why it's not populating the cells? Is my code all correct? Sorry to keep asking you for help.

Comment: Specifically, what's happening is that it's making 2 cells, which are blank, and, therefore, since I've now changed the background colour of the cells to blank, I can only identify that they're there when I click on them and they, therefore, become highlighted. So, there are 2 cells present, but they don't have the same size as the prototype cell and don't have any properties of the prototype cell, at all.

Comment: Here's a visualisation of the behaviour I'm trying to describe: https://imgur.com/a/YgCM2

Comment: Ah, I connect EVERYTHING within the prototype cell, and the prototype cell itself, to the class that handles the view controller?

Comment: Shouldn't the external class I made handle all of the inputs into the fields? I implemented the method I had in my previous class that should satisfy this process, I don't understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: Potentially, could it be that I have to import the table view cells class into the view controllers class?

Comment: If you defined your cell in the Storyboard, then you do **not** need to register the class for your cell, since the Storyboard already did this for you.

Comment: So, what exactly must I do to resolve this issue? Do I make outlets in my view controller's class for the cell itself and each component of the cell's contents? What function can I implement for this?

Comment: For me, with the exact same naming, I've connected those components to the class that I made for handling this tableviewcell

Comment: This is what my pre-existing connections look like: https://imgur.com/a/EoIuh (They link to the code snippet of the second class I included in my main body area of this comment thread).

Comment: Oh, sorry man, unfortunately, Skype got blocked in my country of residence a few weeks ago, it's not possible for me to use that service anymore... :\

Comment: I have seen image and its correct all iboutlets are correctly connected.

Comment: Ok, but they are connected to my "MyListingsTableViewCell" class, not my view controller class. The behaviour observed by the current configuration is as shown in the second last set of imgur links.

Comment: Thats correct you need to connect to iboutlets to `MyListingsTableViewCell` class.

Comment: The datasource and delegate for the table view, in the storyboard, are pointing to the view controller and both of those have been imported into the .h file for the view controller.

Comment: No, I had already done these two things prior to my initial issue here...

Comment: Previously, I followed all of the steps presented in this tutorial: https://theappspace.com/create-dynamic-prototype-cells-in-uitableview-video-tutorial/

Comment: I used the dragging widgets from the storyboard to set them, but imported the protocols in the .h file for the view controller, like in that video I attached. (It has no audio)

Comment: No no...I'm not asking about widgets or views.....I m asking to set datasource and delegate..

Comment: I set those two in the storyboard

Comment: I set them to the view controller. In the storyboard, I attached them to the first item in the hierarchy, the one with orange squares inside an orange circle.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how they're set.

Comment: So I'm not sure what's causing the cells to have an incorrect height + no properties.

Comment: for dynamic cell height...set `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in MyListings.m

Comment: That didn't do anything, for me. It's as if it's ignoring the prototype cell entirely.

Comment: Haha, just as I have ideas and do stuff, my page always refreshes and you reply telling me to do what I did 2 seconds ago. This is great xD

Comment: Haha...so you already debugged it..so tell me it is called or not..??

Comment: It's very strange, actually. It seems as though everything should be working. As the code goes downwards, it recognises that there are 2 elements in the arrays. Then, when it gets to the updateCellWithTitle function, it successfully shows the process of completing the function, by showing me that values are being placed in the .text components of the cells properties, in the other class. However, when we get to return cell, everything is null...

Comment: So, to clarify, it does recognise every single value, correctly, that is being passed to the properties of the instantiated cells. Which is good, however, it returns a blank cell...

Comment: Although the values that the .text properties are being equated to register as the ones in the array, the labels are all still returning "nil" values.

Comment: When I run the code, the values being passed to the .text properties never actually register. So the .text properties for all the labels are always nil, even though the variable they're being equated to show up in the debugger view.

Comment: Are you sure that our files are EXACTLY the same, maybe you added some additions that I might now have? Because my code is genuinely not working...

Comment: There are a few differences between our implementations, actually. My prototype cell had a height of approx. 3 of the regular cells. On top of this, it had properties that were in different locations within this cell. Even when I cut out the external class for this tableviewcell and set string values for the cells properties, the cells properties still don’t appear in the, somewhat, working table cell. On top of that, the cell still shows the ordinary size.

Comment: I know why the properties were ignored, it’s because of that reuse identifier that we declared in the view did load. Because we declared it there, it ignored the one in the function that places values in the cell. However, my last issue is that the height of the prototype cell is being ignored. ONLY the height, which is very strange...