# How to use two tableView in Single viewController on Tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

when I implemented the first tableView and its working fine, however, I try to implement another tableView on the same viewController on Tabbar then the crash occurs.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

[image]

Comment: could u show ur code what u have tried @iOS

Comment: @DilipTiwari, I am not doing anything, I just add the second tableView to ViewController that is in under tabbar and run the app.

Comment: when I using single tableView under tab bar then it's working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526756/unable-to-dequeue-a-cell-with-identifier-cell-must-register-a-nib-or-a-class-f  or please share demo code

Comment: Show your storyboard’s screenshot with two table selected and attribute inspector must be visible in that. I think you are missing cell identifier. Another thing is using cell and missed to register cell class with table view.

Comment: @PaulMarshal, please check the screenshot, 1 identify tableView first and 2 identify tableView second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are putting two table views in the same controller, the delegate/data source for both table views will connect to the same controller. You will have to identify that which table view has to be updated. You can do this by taking the outlets of both the table views and then applying a simple conditional construct in cellForRowAt.

This is how I implemented.

[image: Controller embedded in tab bar, with two table views]

Code

```
    extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == firstTableView
        {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeOne", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
            {
                cell.textLabel?.text = "First table view. Row \(indexPath.row)"
                return cell
            }
            else
            {
                let cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "prototypeOne")
                cell.textLabel?.text = "First table view. Row \(indexPath.row)"
                return cell
            }
        }
        else if tableView == secondTableView
        {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeTwo", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
            {
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Second table view. Row \(indexPath.row)"
                return cell
            }
            else
            {
                let cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "prototypeTwo")
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Second table view. Row \(indexPath.row)"
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Choose your prototipe cell in the Storyboard and set the identifier as Cell in the Inspectors at the right.
Note that this identifier is different to the cell class.

Comment: Please noted I am using with Tabbar

Comment: That’s irrelevant. Your specific error says you’re trying to dequeue a cell with an identifier “Cell” but that identifier isn’t defined to any cell. If you add that identifier to the cell, your error should disappear.

Comment: If you’re using two table views, add outlets to them and compare to the tableView parameter with an `if` statement. According to that, dequeue with one identifier or another. Maybe you only have defined the identifier on one tableView and when dequeuing on the other produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

Register same uitableviewcell in second uitableview.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your both table with tableview object :

create IBOutlet of both table suppose table1 and table2 then in any  delegate/Datasource method of tableview compare tableview and execute code

Eg. : I have define numberOfRowsInSection for 2 tableview

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if(tableView == self.table1)
{
return self.menuTitles.count;
}
else
{
return ModelCollection.count;
}
```