# UITableView programatically added to View Controller won't populate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've programmatically created a `UITableView` within my `MatchCenterViewController`, however it doesn't seem to populate with the JSON data being returned by my cloud code function. It simply shows a blank View Controller. MatchCenterViewController is a ViewController embedded within a Navigation View Controller.

MatchCenterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface MatchCenterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *itemSearch;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageURLs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryCondition;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMaxPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMinPrice;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *matchCenterArray;

@end
```

MatchCenterViewController.m:

```
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchCenterViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *matchCenter;
@end

@implementation MatchCenterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.matchCenter = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _matchCenter.dataSource = self;
        _matchCenter.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.matchCenter];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_matchCenter dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *matchCenterDictionary= [self.matchCenterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [matchCenterDictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];// title of the first object

    //    if([matchCenterDictionary objectForKey:@"Price"] != NULL)
    //    {
    //        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[matchCenterDictionary   objectForKey:@"Price"]];
    //    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
      self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenterTest"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"test": @"Hi",
                                        }
                                block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                         self.matchCenterArray = [result objectForKey:@"Top 3"];

                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                            [_matchCenter reloadData];
                                        });

                                        NSLog(@"Test Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you create this viewController? If you don't use `[[MatchCenterViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:... bundle:...]` the table creation won't be called. This might happen because you have the viewController in a storyBoard, in this case `initWithCoder:` would be the method to overwrite.

I would recommend to move this code to viewDidLoad, which will be called regardless how the viewController was created . E.g.:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.matchCenter = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _matchCenter.dataSource = self;
    _matchCenter.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.matchCenter];

    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Doing that gives me this error: http://codeshare.io/LVKic

Am I missing something?

Comment: As it says in the exception, you did not register a cell with the reuseIdentifier "Cell". Search stackoverflow for this message and you will find [Q: Assertion failure in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath)