# tableview execute before web service call resulting in a blank tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to populate data into a tableview from a web service call. But tableView numberOfRowsInSection executes before I get back my results from the web service call(which brings back data immediately) Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    routes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadDataWithStopName:@""];
    [self.tblview reloadData];

}
```

.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

as you can see, I even tried to reloadData on the tableview property, but it did not work.

Comment: Reload the table after service call is done and result is success. You can post a notification after service call is done. Reload the table in the observer method of that notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that the call to your web service is asynchronous in `loadDataWithStopName`.
This means that `reloadData` will be called even if your web service call is not finished yet.
You have to make sure to call `reloadData` after the data is actually loaded. Like in the callback method of your web service call.

Comment: thanks, that worked.. but now i am getting a different error, 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'  - do you know why that is ?

Comment: @monkeyman, you need to create a prototype cell in your story board. Drag a table view cell onto your table view in the storyboard and name it Cell.

Comment: This is a totally unrelated issue. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath