# Create tableView by storyboard use custom tableViewCell form xib get Assertion failure

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Create `tableView` by `storyboard`, and in the `tableView delegate` method:`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` occurs a exception:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:],
   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3599.6/UITableView.m:6593
```

my code is below:

`ViewController11`

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!  // tableView

// tableview delegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell_id: String = "cell_id"
    // this line below occurs exception: Thread 1:breakpoint 5.2
    var cell: TableViewCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cell_id, for: indexPath) as!  TableViewCell2

    if cell == nil {

        // 
    }

    var title = dataSource[indexPath.row]

    cell.titlelabel?.text = String(title)


    return cell
}
```

and my `storyboard` for `ViewController11`:

[image: viewController11]

and my `xib` for `TableViewCell2`:

[image: TableViewcell12]

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737860/assertion-failure-in-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierforindexpath

Comment: before dequeuing the cell you need to register its `class` or `nib` with the `tableView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register your `UITableViewCell` from the xib before you can use it:

Swift 2:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell2", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_id")
}
```

Swift 3:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell2", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_id")
}
```

Comment: in swift3 `NSBundle.mainBundle()` shold be replace to  `Bundle.main`

Comment: Added the Swift 3 solution. // @aircraft