# What's wrong with register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:) on UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working with an `UICollectionView`. As `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)` expects ***You must register a class or nib file using the `register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)` method before calling this method***, I added a line in my `viewDidLoad` func as

```
self.collectionView!.register(PhotoCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Now when I'm using the cell for dequeuing and configuring, I'm getting error and app crashes.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is my *DataSource* method:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                  for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell

    let aPhoto = photoForIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    cell.imageView.image = aPhoto.thumbnail //this is the line causing error

    return cell
}
```

And this is my `PhotoCollectionViewCell` class

```
class PhotoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! //I double checked this IBOutlet whether it connects with Storyboard or not
}
```

## ***Original question***

Now comes the interesting part.

I'm using a `prototype` cell in the `UICollectionView` and I set a *`reusable identifier`* from *attributes inspector*. Also I changed the *custom class* from *identity inspector* to my `PhotoCollectionViewCell`.

I searched for the same issue and found out that when using prototype cell, deleting

```
self.collectionView!.register(PhotoCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

from code will work. I gave it a try and it works.

> But I'm curious to know the reason behind this issue. I couldn't reproduce the same issue with `UITableView` but with `UICollectionView`.

### Not a possible duplicate:

This [UICollectionView's cell registerClass in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110811/uicollectionviews-cell-registerclass-in-swift) is about how to register class in `UICollectionView`. But my question doesn't expect ***how to register***. My question is about an issue that isn't true with `UITableView` class but with `UICollectionView` only. I'm expecting the actual difference between this conflicting issue.

Comment: Have you added cell identifier in cell in storyboard??

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal, yes! I also mentioned this.

Comment: did you use separate xib and custom class ?

Comment: The prototype cell is connected automatically. If tou register class for the same identifier, you overwrite that connection but no views will be loaded therefore outlets will stay nil. You cannot connect storyboard cells programatically.

Comment: @KKRocks I used `prototype cell` but with custom class.

Comment: in storyboard ?

Comment: @KKRocks yes! In storyboard.

Comment: then you dont need to register cell in viewDidLoad...Remove that line form viewDidLoad.

Comment: @nayem Add this func code -> `photoForIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)`. Put breakpoint and check `aPhoto`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView's cell registerClass in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110811/uicollectionviews-cell-registerclass-in-swift)

Comment: @dahiya_boy, I tested that out. `aPhoto` is containing expected value. The problem is in `cell.imageView` as this remains ___nil___.

Comment: @nayem Check Cell object.

Comment: @nayem check either you give the identifier to the custom cell from the storyboard/XIB or not?

Comment: @dahiya_boy I did give the `reusable identifier` for the cell in ___attributes inspector___

Comment: @Sulthan it seems my issue is conflicting with [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43400993/3687801)

Comment: I dont see a conflict.

Comment: Yes! He was using a `prototype` cell giving it an _identifier_ and assigning a _custom class_. But yet the answer suggested to use `tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`. And I was also doing the same but with `UICollectionView`. So why shouldn't I need to register cell's class? @Sulthan

Comment: You write: *"cell.imageView.image = aPhoto.thumbnail //this is the line causing error"* .. so, which part is causing the error? the `cell.imageView.image` reference or the `aPhoto.thumbnail` reference? Set a debug breakpoint and check, or better, use `if let photoThumb = aPhoto.thumbnail as? UIImage { }` and make sure it's a valid UIImage.

Comment: Actually `cell.imageView` was having _nil_ value. But Sulthan's answer below solved my problem @DonMag

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 3 ways to register a cell (either for `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`).

1. You can register a class. That means the cell has no nib or storyboard. No UI will be loaded and no outlets connected, only the class initializer is called automatically.
2. You can register a `UINib` (that is, a `xib` file). In that case the cell UI is loaded from the xib and outlets are connected.
3. You can create a prototype cell in the storyboard. In that case the cell is registered automatically for that specific `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController`. The cell is not accessible in any other controller.

The options cannot be combined. If you have a cell prototype in the storyboard, you don't have to register again and if you do, you will break the storyboard connection.

Comment: That was what I needed to know. I used the register method (the documentation says you should, the template provides the stub), and all my outlets were nil. Remove the 'necessary' method, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign Nib to Collection view cell with an identifier as follows :

```
self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "nibName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Hope it helps.