# UILabel in UITableViewCell returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set an UITableView in an UIViewController.
The UITableView has UITableViewCells which has an UILabel.

However, UITableView.UILabels return nil.

Please see the following codes and images and share your thoughts.

Thank you in advance.

I am developing this with Swift5.

```swift
import UIKit

class condimentTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var condimentName: UILabel!
}

class SandwichViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var condimentTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var breadSelector: UIPickerView!

    fileprivate let items:[product] = products().getData()
    fileprivate let cart:cart = Registry.instance.liveCart

    var itemNo: Int = 0
    let condiments = ["Lettuce", "Mayo", "Mustard", "Purple Onions", "Tomato"]
    let breads = ["Rye", "Sourdough", "Squaw", "Wheat", "White"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
        self.breadSelector.dataSource = self
        self.breadSelector.delegate = self
        self.condimentTable.register(condimentTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "condimentCell")
        self.condimentTable.delegate = self
        self.condimentTable.dataSource = self
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return condiments.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:condimentTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "condimentCell", for: indexPath) as! condimentTableCell
        if (cell.condimentName == nil) {
            print("nil")
        } else {
            cell.condimentName.text = condiments[indexPath.row]
        }
        print("----------------------------------------------")
        return cell
    }


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return breads.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return breads[row]
    }
}
```

[simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzPuL.png)

[print result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS9h5.png)

[Storyboard-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idkxS.png)

[Storyboard-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izWH6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove line

```
self.condimentTable.register(condimentTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "condimentCell")
```

You are breaking the storyboard connection to the cell.

For detailed explanation see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44107114/669586