# detailTextLabel not showing initially

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using a static UITableview, set up in a storyboard. For some cells (Style = Right detail) I set the detailTextlabel.text in viewWillAppear like this:

```
   self.recentProductsCell.detailTextLabel.text = description;
```

For this cell the label does not appear. If I NSLog the text it shows to be OK.
I checked that the detailTextLabel is not hidden.
I did not change any of the other properties in storyboard.
The cell has a detailDisclosure accessory, but setting it to something else did not help.

Then the strange thing:
If I run and the detailTextlabel does not show, I select the row by tapping on it and moving my finger. From then the detailTextLabel does show! Even when hiding and reshowing the view, the label keeps visible. Resetting and setting it in code however, makes the label disappear again.

Could I be doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Edited: Checked in both 5.0 and 5.1, same behavior. 
I found an ugly workaround by Selecting and Deselecting this row in code in the viewWillAppear. So I added:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0] animated:NO];
```

It works, but I can see the row being selected and deselected. So I also changed the selectionStyle, but now this row flickers when the view is shown.

Extra comment: In the same viewWillAppear, I set the detailLabel of other static cells, and they show up just fine.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code (if any) for cell creation and reuse? I still have a few theories as to why this behavior is occurring but I need to see more code to nail it down.

Comment: Sorry for now. Maybe after the Easter days, small holiday coming. I think it is so strange that I want to try to reproduce in a project build from scratch and submit a bug report to Apple. Just for the experience. But it will take some time. Maybe tuesday. Thanks for your interest for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did find when the detailLabel did not show up, not why, IMHO it's a bug.

If the previous value for the detailLabel.Text was nil or an empty string, the detailLabel does not show up after setting it to the new value. 
If I set the detailLabel to anything else than nil/empty (initially), and then set it to something else, the new value correctly shows up.

The reason for not showing is probably more complicated then just being empty before, but in my case this solves my problem. I can probably show the detailLabel in the background colour if I want it to be "empty".

Comment: Thanks, another weird bug from apple.

Comment: 2019 - still bug :-). When I select the row then detail label appears

Answer (score 5):

I've got a duplicate of this issue. Same configuration - static cells in a storyboard, but with left detail cells. I also see the issue where touching the cell makes it visible.

I worked around this by setting the initial detail label content in the storyboard to a single space. After setting the actual detail label content in code, I send a sizeToFit message to the detail label.

Comment: I ran into this bug again and am more experienced now. Your answer is correct in that setting an initial value in the storyBoard helps. I did not need to send sizeToFit to the detail label. On inspection in the debugger I found that the detaillabel does not have a correct size and origin if no default is specified in the storyboard. Only sending a sizeToFit does change the size of the frame, but not the origin. My problem is solved.

Comment: Size to fit worked as a good workaround for me.  Has anyone reported this to Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set cell Style = subtitle

Comment: Same problem remains. No subtitle shown initially, but shown after selecting the row. Main title is shown centered initially, and pops to the top to make room for the detailLabel.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the the label in the wrong place.

Post your UITableViewDelegate / DataSource code. You need to set this value in either `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or `willDisplayCellAtIndexPath:`

Comment: No, because I am using STATIC cells, created in the storyboard by setting Content in the Attributes inspector for the UITableView to: Static Cells. See also the answer for the question in: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863775/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-within-a-storyboard)

Comment: You can still use `willDisplayCellAtIndexPath`. This will allow you to make final changes immediately prior to the cell being drawn on the screen.

Comment: Alas, willDisplayCellAtIndexPath is only fired when the tableview is first constructed for static cells, from: -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] . After that this method is not fired when the cell is shown. (And yes, the delegate is set to the controller..).

Comment: I also tried moving the code to tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: but the result is the same. The call to this method is not made for every appearance of the table, but only for the initial creation. My tableView is never released because it is the master in a splitViewController. Maybe I should force a release on hide?

Comment: BTW: I tried cellForRowAtIndexPath because the docs said it would be the proper way: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding all controls to the `contentView` of the UITableViewCell? If you simply add it to the cell this can sometimes result in wonky behavior.

Comment: I am using the predefined type UITableViewCellStyleValue2 (by selecting Style = Right Detail in IB). So I don't do custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I think it's a bug.
If I hold my tap on the line, I see the detailTextLabel.

As Bjinse said, it occurs generally if you set the detailTextLabel previously to nil or "" (without space = empty string).

So I ended setting the detailTextLabel that I wanted empty to " " (with a space). That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found it only happens on iPhone 6plus(8.4) in my case.

Solution 1(Suggest):

After not reusing the cell, problem solved.

```
//var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)
//if cell == nil {
//    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
//}

var cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

Solution 2:

Because the text shows after we scroll or touch, so I decide to reload data. This also works, but there's a delay between the view shows and the detailText text shows.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```